# Помогите решить задачу по теории вероятности!

Tags: математика, графы, теория-вероятностей

> Вы попали в лабиринт, состоящий из нескольких комнат, соединенных системой двусторонних порталов. Каждый портал соединяет только одну пару комнат лабиринта. Порталом можно пользоваться неограниченное число раз. Вы появляетесь в комнате v1 и прыжками перемещаетесь между комнатами. В комнате v6 находится выход из лабиринта. Предположим, что каждый следующий портал для прыжка вы выбираете случайно и равновероятно среди всех порталов в этой комнате, включая портал до предыдущей комнаты. Найдите математическое ожидание количества прыжков до первого попадания в v6.
>
> [image: Лабиринт]

Так как мы спавнимся в точке 1, минимальное количество шагов до точке 6 - это 2 (1-2-6, 1-3-6). Соответственно случайная величина может принимать значения от 2 и до какого-то  N. Дальше я читал всевозможные вероятности для каждого числа шагов( например для того, что X=2, вероятность равна (0.5 * 0.25 + 0.5 * 0.25) - (1 - 2 - 6, 1 - 3 - 6). Но уже для 4 считать оказывается проблематично, так как с увеличением числа шагов на 1, способов добраться до вершины 6 увеличивается в 2 раза.(Например для 3 шагов: 1 - 2 - 4 - 6, 1 - 2 - 3 - 6 и.т.д). И вот я не понимаю одного, как дальше считать матожидание, если вероятности отличаются! Пробовал еще подогнать под экспоненциальный закон, но понял, что СВ дискретная.

Comment: Ну хоть бы чуть-чуть что-то сделали! Интересная же задача, так и хочется помочь... А - никак: *
Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи.*

Comment: Кстати, ответ - 5,(3). И аналитически, и экспериментально :) Вобщем, сделаете хоть что-то - буду голосовать за переоткрытие. Нет - ну что ж, на нет и суда нет...

Comment: Прошу меня извинить, я впервые пользуюсь форумами! Я добавил свои рассуждения.

Comment: Проголосовал за переоткрытие; если найдется достаточно голосов - покажу, как легко решить эту задачу :) Пока - только экспериментальное подтверждение ответа: https://ideone.com/KZ2KAG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подойдем к решению, как настоящие программисты - рекурсивно :) От математиков воспользуемся симметрией - понятно, что узлы 2 и 3 равнозначны, как и узлы 4 и 5.

Пусть Среднее количество шагов из узла 1 до узла 6 - K, от узлов 2 и 3 - N, а от узлов 4 и 5 - M.

Из узла 1 мы можем попасть одним ходом в узлы 2 или 3, т.е.

```
K = (1/2)*(1+N) + (1/2)*(1+N)
```

- два равновероятных хода в узлы 2 и 3, а оттуда - за N шагов из каждого.

Для узлов 2 и 3 есть по 4 равновероятных хода - т.е.

```
N = (1/4)*(1+N) + (1/4)*(1+M) + (1/4)*(1+K) + (1/4)*(1+0)
```

(попадание в узлы 3 (или 2, для узла 3), 4 (или 5 для узла 3), 1 и 6 соответственно), так что

```
N = 1 + (M+N+K)/4
```

Для узлов 4 и 5 точно так же получаем

```
M = (1/3)*(1+M) + (1/3)*(1+N) + (1/3)*(1+0)
```

Итого - имеем систему уравнений

```
K = 1 + N
N = 1 + (N+M+K)/4
M = 1 + (M+N)/3
```

Решая ее, находим K = 16/3.

Экспериментальная проверка - программа, которая много-много раз имитирует случайные блуждания - находится [здесь](https://ideone.com/KZ2KAG).

Comment: Можно только добавить что для произвольного графа такую систему может строить и решать компьютер автоматически.